# Can you set Process Monitor to filter multiple file types instead of a single file type? Or all sounds?

Tags: audio, system-sounds, sysinternals, process-monitor, file-filter

I'm trying to figure out which programs are making certain sounds and the only tool that I've come across to have that ability is Syinternals Process Monitor.

[Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTM0E.png)

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to filter out multiple file-types at a time. Instead, I have to filter for .wav... Then .mp3, etc...

Is there an option I'm missing that will allow me to filter multiple file types or all sounds?

Or a program (other than Volume Mixer) that can help with this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All those PATH filter rules you have are automatically OR'd together by ProcMon, so yes it is filtering events on all those file-types at once.

There is no capability to filter on "sounds".